# Segmentation fault with message received for client

Tags: c, sockets, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a simple client-server program. My server receives a message and prints it into stdout.

Client code:

```
...
int message_length = strlen(message);
sent_bytes = send(socket, &message_length, sizeof(int), 0);
<... check ...>
sent_bytes = send(socket, message, strlen(message)*sizeof(char), 0);
<... check ...>
...
```

Server code:

```
...
got_bytes = recv(socket, &message_length, sizeof(int), 0);
<... check ...> 
message = malloc( (message_length+10)*sizeof(char)); 
got_bytes = recv(socket, &message, message_length*sizeof(char), 0);
<... check ...>
printf("Length: %d\n", message_length); 
strcat(message, '\0');
printf("%s\n", message);
...
```

Executing:

```
$ ./client Message!

$ ./server
Length: 8
Segmentation fault
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Is message originally null-terminated? Try replacing strcat with something like `message[message_length] = 0` instead. Or have the client send a message with \0 already as part of the packet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crux of the problem is here: `strcat(message, '\0');`

`strcat` takes two strings as arguments, and `\0` is not a string, it is a character.  Furthermore, if `message` is not already null-terminated with a `\0`, then `strcat` will fail because it will seek to the end of `message` by *looking for a null terminator*, in order to figure out where to append the right-hand argument.  So, not even `strcat(message, "")` would work.

Probably the right solution for you is the following: in the client portion, change the `send` portion to send `strlen(message) + 1` bytes.  Assuming that `message` gets null-terminated on the client side when  `message` is generated, this will cause the `send` operation to send the null-terminator as well, and it will be received by the server.  Then you can get rid of your `strcat(message, '\0')` snippets altogether.

Edit: you will also need to adjust the server portion to `recv` one extra byte of `message`, to get the null terminator.